# iFrame nested in iFrame with same ID

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, markup, semantic-markup

I'm using the frameElement.id JavaScript property to make some changes to the page when nested in a particular iFrame.

There is a case where I have an iFrame with that ID nested in an iFrame with that ID. So it looks like:

---

> **Main Page:**

```
<body>
    <iframe src="url.htm" id="show_body_only"></iframe>
</body>
```

---

> **url.htm:**

```
<body>
    <iframe src="url2.htm" id="show_body_only"></iframe>
</body>
```

---

Just wondering if this is semantically correct.

*Please do not berate for all the iFrames, I had little choice.*

Comment: Just run your page through a validator when you're concerned about HTML validity. http://html5.validator.nu

Comment: I think that it is okay on other depth

Answer (score 1):

As far as CSS, the spec says:

> no two such attributes can have the same value in a conformant document

If the frames explicitly share stylesheets, then the IDs will be applied separately since each frame is its own document.

As far as the DOM, the spec says:

> The getElementById(elementId) method must return the first element, in tree order, within context object's descendants, whose ID is elementId, and null if there is no such element otherwise. 
>   A node's node document can be changed by the adopt algorithm.

If the frame nodes are imported and adopted, then `getElementById` returns the first match.

**References**

- [CSS3: ID Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors)
- [DOM4 Concepts: node document](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-document)
- [Document.adoptNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode)
- [DOM4 5.2.2: Interface NonElementParentNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid)